# Python Tkinter - Update while funtion in running

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm learning Tkinter by making a GUI for a sudoku solver program (that was arleady built).

On the click of a button, the algorithm that solves the sudoku runs and sometimes it takes some time.

How could I update the sudoku on the screen when the function is called, so that users can see how its running?

I'm working with a gui script separate from the sudoku one, is it correct, in design terms, to have the gui and the logic separate?

Thank in advance

**EDIT**

This is my code:

Sudoku.py

```
class Sudoku(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__matrix = [[(0, Status.Guess) for x in range(9)] for y in range(9)]
    ...
    def solveSudoku(self):
        ...
```

GUI.py

```
class App:

    def __init__(self, master, su):
        self.__sudoku__ = su
        self.__root__ = master
        self.__entries__ = {}
        fsudoku = Frame(master)
        fsudoku.grid(row=0)
        self.displaysudoku(fsudoku) """grid of entrys"""
        tButton = Button(master,text="Solve", command=self.SolveAndDisplay)
        ...

    def refreshSudokuGrid(self):
        """USED AFTER SOLVING A SUDOKU"""
        for i in range(1,10):
            for j in range(1,10):
                val = self.__sudoku__.value(i,j)
                self.__entries__[i * 10 +j].delete(0, END)
                if (val!= 0):
                    self.__entries__[i * 10 + j].insert(0, val)
    def SolveAndDisplay(self):
        self.scanSudoku()
        self.__sudoku__.solveSudoku()
        self.refreshSudokuGrid()
    ...

root = Tk()
su = Sudoku()
s = App(root, su)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "is it correct, in design terms, to have the gui and the logic separate?" Not only is it correct, but it is also best practice. You're doing the right thing, especially from a Pythonic point of view, that tends to make everything modular.

Comment: I agree that it's a _very_ good idea to keep the GUI code and the Sudoku-solving logic separate. However, I suggest you look for a more efficient Sudoku solver. The one you're using looks like it does a very primitive brute-force search, which is why it can be so slow. Please see [this page](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~aassaf9/python/algorithm_x.html) by Ali Assaf, which is a short article about Exact Cover problems and how Knuth's Algorithm X can be used to solve them. That page contains a link to a Python 3 Sudoku solver written by Ali which will find the solution in under one second.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you must be using some loop which solves the sudoku.**If this is true**:

The place where your function/command for your button is defined,
place the following code at the beginning of the primary loop which solves the sudoku (assuming root is your tkinter window):

```
root.update()
```

As such such a method is not fully threadsafe, but should solve the problem for general cases like yours.

Keeping GUI and logic separate is the best practice.

Comment: the problem is that i have the gui separate from the programs logic, so root is not defined in the function that solves the sudoku.

Comment: Is all your code in the same program, if Yes , define root at the beginning of your program ( ie before all functions)   root = Tk(), it must work since root encompasses all properties and modules in your GUI.

Comment: Probably , you can add another parameter(which takes a window object) in your constructor/instantiation  of class Sudoku. then pass root object to the Sudoku object created,like this :    Sudoku(root) in GUI.py